# How to index a tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, matlab, pytorch

I'm having some trouble with `pytorch`. 
When calculating `mu` and `sig` this message appears:
**ValueError: result of slicing is an empty tensor**

Here's my code:

```
x            = mu + sig*torch.randn(N,1)
S            = -x**2 + 100
sorted_v , I = torch.sort(S,0)
mu           = alpha*torch.mean(x[I[(1-rho)*N:N]]) + (1-alpha)*mu
sig          = alpha*torch.std(x[I[(1-rho)*N:N]])  + (1-alpha)*sig
```

In `MATLAB` I would do something like this:

```
mu    = alpha*mean(x(I((1-rho)*N:N))) + (1-alpha)*mu;
sig   = alpha*std(x(I((1-rho)*N:N)))  + (1-alpha)*sig;
```

What is wrong and why? 
Thak you so much.

Comment: which line are you getting the error? and what is the initial value of mu and sig? i can't run the code provided to check for error. please provide more information so that we can help you.

Comment: @WasiAhmad my bad. 

I forgot to tell the parameter:  `N`       = 100; `rho`     = 1/N; alpha   = 0.8; `epsilon` = 0.001;
`mu`      = 20*torch.rand(1,1)-10; # init mu
`sig`     = 10;           # initial std dev.

Comment: @WasiAhmad The line where I'm getting error is :
mu           = alpha*torch.mean(x[I[(1-rho)*N:N]]) + (1-alpha)*mu

Answer (score 0):

Since you are code is not runnable, I can't offer you the solution to resolve the error. But I can tell why you are probably getting the error.

In the following two lines of your code:

```
mu  = alpha * torch.mean(x[I[(1-rho)*N:N]]) + (1-alpha) * mu
sig = alpha * torch.std(x[I[(1-rho)*N:N]]) + (1-alpha) * sig
```

`I[(1-rho)*N:N]` or `x[I[(1-rho)*N:N]]` is returning an empty tensor. A simple way to understand the reason for the error is to print the shapes of `x` and `I`. And also print the values of `rho` and `N`.

Comment: I did that and both have torch.Size([100, 1]), torch.Size([100, 1])

Comment: N = 100 and rho = 1/N, but rho comes out as an empty tensor...why?

Comment: I found the mistake. Cheers!